# Traversal pointer in tree while insertion

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *right;
    node *left;
} ;

node *root = NULL;
node *right = NULL;
node *left = NULL;

node insert(int data)
{
    node *ptr = new node;
    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->left = NULL;
    ptr->right = NULL;

    if(root==NULL)
    {
        root = ptr;
        cout<<"Inserted "<<root->data<<" at root\n";
    }
    else
    {
        node *pos = root;
        while(pos)
        {
            cout<<pos->data<<" pos->data\n";
            if(pos->data > data)
            {
                cout<<pos->data<<": data\n";
                pos = pos->left;
            }
            else if(pos->data < data)
            {
                cout<<pos->data<<": data\n";
                pos = pos->right;
            }
            if(!pos)
                cout<<"NULL\n";
        }
        pos = ptr;
        cout<<"Inserted\n";
    }
    return *root;
}

void preorder(node *root)
{
    if(root)
    {
        cout<<root->data;
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    insert(2);
    insert(1);
    insert(3);
    insert(4);
    insert(5);
    preorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, while inserting the new element, I am pointing `root` to new variable `pos` so that root is unaltered so that it becomes parameter to the function `preorder()` properly as it is the actual root

But, `pos` isn't inserting all the elements and also not displaying the required results. In short I have to use `root` instead of `pos` to insert, but using root directly is altering the 'actual' root (which in this case is 2).

Comment: Don't put the C and C++ tag on the same question, if you want help with your C++ program.

Comment: Don't use global variables, they are very error prone and it is almost always better to use scoped variables.

Comment: Also, what is your actual question?!

Comment: Okay!! Understood :D

Comment: just the variable pos isn't giving required result.It is not traversing the nodes. It just keep displaying the root again and again. replacing pos with root is giving the solution but the root pointer is changed.

Comment: Please don't post it in the comments, but edit your question and add the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, pos isn't inserting all the elements and also not displaying the required results.

I think there are mainly two bugs.

- `root` is never updated in the current `insert` function because `ptr` is just only assigned to a temporal variable `pos` after while loop finished.
- We should consider the case that the value of the passed argument `data` is already saved in the binary tree.

In addition, `preorder` is displaying the `root` again and again is confusing.
An example of fixing the `insert` and `preorder` is following one.
[**DEMO is here.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ec6f9be5920fd56)

```
node insert(int data)
{
    node *ptr = new node;
    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->left = nullptr;
    ptr->right = nullptr;

    if(!root)
    {
        root = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        node *pos = root;

        while(true)
        {
            if(pos->data > data)
            {
                if(!pos->left){
                    pos->left = ptr;
                    break;
                }

                pos = pos->left;
            }
            else if(pos->data < data)
            {
                if(!pos->right){
                    pos->right = ptr;
                    break;
                }

                pos = pos->right;                
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return *root;
}

void preorder(node *next)
{
    if(next)
    {
        cout << next->data << std::endl;
        preorder(next->left);
        preorder(next->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes!! got the logic. Thanks :D